# Implement first last in Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to implement First and last in my navigation using nhibernate.On click of first i am able to find first row using given function

```
public IList<T> GetFirstItem<T>()
    {
        using (ISession session = MvcApplication.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession())
        {
            using (session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).SetFirstResult(0)
                .SetMaxResults(1)
               .List<T>();
            }
        }
    }
```

But i am not able to implement last button.I dont want to use two queries. Is it possible to find last item in a single Nhibernate query?

Comment: Usually SetFirstResult and SetMaxResults are used to implement paging with NH. is it something you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want to use some kind of sorting to determine first and last items, so you could use sort ASC to get the first and use DESC to get the last with adding sorting to your current code.

Comment: Thanks Low Flying Pelican. I elaborated my problem.Thats why i cant use AddOrder(Order.Desc) ..

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `GetFirstItem()` does not guarantee to return the first item since a select query may return items in whatever order it pleases. So you get the first result in a random list.

To get your method to work properly you need to add a `.AddOrder(Order.Asc("<some property>"))` call to your criteria where `<some property>` could be a database id or a creation timestamp.

To get the last item, add a `.AddOrder(Order.Desc("<some property>"))` call instead.

(By the way, why do you return a list from a method that should get you one item only?)

Comment: Thanks Torbjörn Kalin. In my table there is no identity nor any timestamp.I am implementing string as primary key.So applying order will not give last value.My previous function was---             ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T));       return criteria.AddOrder(Order.Asc(a_PKColName)).SetMaxResults(1).List<T>(); where a_PKColName is primary key. and yes,you are right,i shoudn't use list to return single item.